# Using AND/OR in if else PHP statement

Tags: php, if-statement

How do you use 'AND/OR' in an if else PHP statement? Would it be:

1) AND

```
if ($status = 'clear' AND $pRent == 0) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE rent 
                    SET dNo = '$id', 
                        status = 'clear', 
                        colour = '#3C0' 
                  WHERE rent.id = $id");
}
```

2) OR

```
if ($status = 'clear' OR $pRent == 0) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE rent 
                    SET dNo = '$id', 
                        status = 'clear', 
                        colour = '#3C0' 
                  WHERE rent.id = $id");
}
```

Comment: How this will work??

`$items_list = array(2,177);`


`$rules_list = array(
    '[(13  OR 3  OR 2 )]',
    '[(54  OR 77 ) AND 17  AND 59  AND 36 ] OR [(2  AND 36 )]',
    '[(2  OR 3  OR 13 ) AND 30 ]',
    '[(2 )] OR [(13  OR 4 ) AND (17 )]',
    '[(2 )] OR [(13  OR 3 ) AND 17 ]',
    '[(2  AND 30 ) OR (3  AND 30 )]',
);`


//Calculate the bool result of each rule using the provided items array`

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Yes. The answer is yes.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

---

Two things though:

- Many programmers prefer `&&` and `||` instead of `and` and `or`, but they work the same (safe for precedence).
- `$status = 'clear'` should probably be `$status == 'clear'`. `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.

Answer (score 36):

There's some joking, and misleading comments, even partially incorrect information in the answers here. I'd like to try to improve on them:

**First**, as some have pointed out, you have a bug in your code that relates to the question:

```
if ($status = 'clear' AND $pRent == 0)
```

should be (note the `==` instead of `=` in the first part):

```
if ($status == 'clear' AND $pRent == 0)
```

which *in this case* is functionally equivalent to

```
if ($status == 'clear' && $pRent == 0)
```

**Second**, note that these operators (`and or && ||`) are short-circuit operators. That means if the answer can be determined with certainty from the first expression, the second one is never evaluated. Again this doesn't matter for your debugged line above, but it is extremely important when you are combining these operators with assignments, because

**Third**, the real difference between `and or` and `&& ||` is their [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). Specifically the importance is that `&& ||` have higher precedence than the assignment operators (`= += -= *= **= /= .= %= &= |= ^= <<= >>=`) while `and or` have lower precendence than the assignment operators. Thus in a statement that combines the use of assignment and logical evaluation it matters which one you choose.

Modified examples from [PHP's page on logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php):

```
$e = false || true;
```

will evaluate to `true` and assign that value to `$e`, because `||` has higher operator precedence than `=`, and therefore it essentially evaluates like this:

```
$e = (false || true);
```

however

```
$e = false or true;
```

will assign `false` to `$e` (and then perform the `or` operation and evaluate `true`) because `=` has higher operator precedence than `or`, essentially evaluating like this:

```
($e = false) or true;
```

The fact that this ambiguity even exists makes a lot of programmers just always use `&& ||` and then everything works clearly as one would expect in a language like C, ie. logical operations first, then assignment.

Some languages like Perl use this kind of construct frequently in a format similar to this:

```
$connection = database_connect($parameters) or die("Unable to connect to DB.");
```

This would theoretically assign the database connection to `$connection`, or if that failed (and we're assuming here the function would return something that evalues to `false` in that case), it will end the script with an error message. Because of short-circuiting, if the database connection succeeds, the `die()` is never evaluated.

Some languages that allow for this construct straight out forbid assignments in conditional/logical statements (like Python) to remove the amiguity the other way round.

PHP went with allowing both, so you just have to learn about your two options once and then code how you'd like, but hopefully you'll be consistent one way or another.

Whenever in doubt, just throw in an extra set of parenthesis, which removes all ambiguity. These will always be the same:

```
$e = (false || true);
$e = (false or true);
```

Armed with all that knowledge, I prefer using `and or` because I feel that it makes the code more readable. I just have a rule not to combine assignments with logical evaluations. But at that point it's just a preference, and consistency matters a lot more here than which side you choose.

Answer (score 21):

A bit late but don't matter...
the question is "How do you use...?" short answer is you are doing it correct

---

The other question would be "When do you use it?"
I use `&&` instead of `AND` and `||` instead of `OR`.

```
$a = 1
$b = 3
```

Now,

```
if ($a == 1 && $b == 1) { TRUE } else { FALSE }
```

in this case the result is "FALSE" because B is not 1, now what if

```
if ($a == 1 || $b == 1) { TRUE } else { FALSE }
```

This will return "TRUE" even if B still not the value we asking for, there is another way to return TRUE without the use of OR / || and that would be XOR

```
if ($a == 1 xor $b == 1) { TRUE } else { FALSE }
```

in this case we need only one of our variables to be true BUT NOT BOTH if both are TRUE the result would be FALSE.

more in: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 11):

AND is `&&` and OR is `||` like in C.

Answer (score 10):

You have 2 issues here.

1. use `==` for comparison. You've used `=` which is for assignment.
2. use `&&` for "and" and `||` for "or". `and` and `or` will work but they are unconventional.

Comment: It's rare, but maybe they wanted to assign in that condition :P Though I'm betting they didn't.

Comment: @alex: Certainly not in the case of `if ($status = 'clear' OR $pRent == 0) {`. In that case, the second condition is unreachable. It's got to be an error.

Comment: Yep, definitely not with the `OR`.

Answer (score 5):

`AND` and `OR` are just syntactic sugar for `&&` and `||`, like in JavaScript, or other C styled syntax languages.

It [appears `AND` and `OR` have lower precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than their C style equivalents.

Answer (score 3):

for  AND you use

```
if ($status = 'clear' && $pRent == 0) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE rent SET dNo = '$id', status = 'clear', colour = '#3C0' WHERE rent.id = $id");
}
```

for  OR you use

```
if ($status = 'clear' || $pRent == 0) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE rent SET dNo = '$id', status = 'clear', colour = '#3C0' WHERE rent.id = $id");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think i am having a bit of confusion here. :) But seems no one else have ..

Are you asking which one to use in this scenario? If Yes then **And is the correct answer**.

If you are asking about how the operators are working, then

In php both **AND, &&** and **OR, ||** will work in the same way. If you are new in programming and php is one of your first languages them i suggest using AND and OR, because it increases readability and reduces confusion when you check back. But if you are familiar with any other languages already then you might already have familiarized the && and || operators.

Comment: This is simply incorrect. AND/OR have lower precedence than assignment while &&/|| have higher precedence. The classic example: `$e = false || true;` vs `$e = false or true;`. The first one evaluates to true, the second to false.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$val1 = rand(1,4); 
$val2=rand(1,4); 

if ($pars[$last0] == "reviews" && $pars[$last] > 0) { 
    echo widget("Bootstrap Theme - Member Profile - Read Review",'',$w[website_id],$w);
} else { ?>
    <div class="w100">
        <div style="background:transparent!important;" class="w100 well" id="postreview">
            <?php 
            $_GET[user_id] = $user[user_id];
            $_GET[member_id] = $_COOKIE[userid];
            $_GET[subaction] = "savereview"; 
            $_GET[ip] = $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]; 
            $_GET[httpr] = $_ENV[requesturl]; 
            echo form("member_review","",$w[website_id],$w);?>
        </div></div>
```

ive replaced the 'else' with '&&' so both are placed ... argh

Answer (score -1):

"AND" does not work in my PHP code.

Server's version maybe?

"&&" works fine.

Comment: AND is not a php keyword, the syntax is `&&` for AND.

Comment: @php_coder_3809625 for your kind reference http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Comment: @php_coder_3809625 For your checking / reading https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp