# Using "or" correctly in PHP with an if statement

Tags: php

I want to check if either of these checkboxes are checked and if either of them are i want the new assigned variable $open_monday to = "yes else "no".

```
   if (isset($_POST['open_monday_lunch'] or $_POST['opening_monday1'])) {

        $open_monday = "yes";

   }

   else { $open_monday = "no"; }
```

Is that the right way to do it? I have never used `or` before. I just get a blank pag when trying to run it as if the syntax is incorrect.

Comment: This is not how you use the or operator! do: `isset($_POST['open_monday_lunch']) || isset($_POST['opening_monday1']))` You don't use it in the function call itself

Comment: possible duplicate of [using AND/OR in if else PHP statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405795/using-and-or-in-if-else-php-statement). Also, is it really that difficult to google? Or even turn on error reporting?

Comment: Your most obvious problem is that you have missed out some brackets. It should be `if ( isset($_POST['open_monday_lunch']) or isset($_POST['opening_monday1']) ) {` regardless of whether you use `||` or `OR` But you should also read this answer before moving from using '&&' and '||' to `AND` and `OR`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803321/and-vs-as-operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to Operator precedence its always preferable to use `&&` instead of `and` ,similarly `||` instead of `or`.please refer [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) for additional info,

so try like this,

```
 if (isset($_POST['open_monday_lunch'] ) || isset( $_POST['opening_monday1'])) {

        $open_monday = "yes";

   }

   else { $open_monday = "no"; }
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Still showing as blank on this. what does || mean? Or?

Comment: @SpringheeledJack `||` is the same operator as `or` just with a higher precedence

Comment: @sgtBOSE I thought that they would recognize it, but apparently not :)

Comment: @Rizier123 they are still not getting that.

Comment: I get this message if I dont check that box using this code.

Notice: Undefined index: open_monday1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/welcometowarwick/scripts/php/insert_restaurant.php on line 108

Comment: This code has still a syntax error in it! And it is accepted ?!

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with -

```
if (!empty($_POST['open_monday_lunch']) || !empty($_POST['opening_monday1'])) {
```

Comment: `empty()` might not be necessary here or maybe even break the code if OP has a value attr. for the checkboxes with an empty value or false would it return false even if they are set

Comment: @Rizier123 thats the main point. If OP want to check for the same then can use this. :)